# Regex in a Tweet: match @reply WITHOUT matching @mention

Tags: regex, match, tweets

I am working with Tweets.

I am looking for a regular expression that matches all the replies ***@reply*** that are present in the beginning of a Tweet **WITHOUT** matching the mentions ***@mention***.

For example I have this Tweeet:

@AlexWassabi @laurDIY now i type my text and i mention @mention

I would like to match @AlexWassabi and @laurDIY **WITHOUT** matching @mention.

Please note that in this example there are 2 replies (e.g @AlexWassabi and @laurDIY) but in reality  we can have more *@replies* that are followed by each other, then we have text and then we have a mention.

Could please suggest a regular expression that does this job?

Thank you.

Comment: `^(@\w+\s)+`  will match all the prefixed "@reply" at beginning of string only.  https://regex101.com/r/CVyZOa/2/

Comment: @sweaver2112 thanks a lot for your answer, I would like to accept your anser but how do i do when its in your comment? (im new to stackoverflow)

Comment: sure, converted to answer.  good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(@\w+\s)+` will match all the prefixed "@reply"(s) at beginning of string only. 
[regex101.com demo](http://regex101.com/r/CVyZOa/2)